# How to make active class in <ul> <li> menu visible at loading page first

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm just begin learn js, and have a problem.
This sidebar menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/q8b041s5/

How i can get visible display block, if line `<li>` or `<ul>` is active? 
Tis need, when go to link, sidebar menu was in the same place of click.

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#cssmenu > ul > li ul').each(function (index, e) {

                $(e).closest('li').children('a');
            });

            $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {
                $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
                $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
                var checkElement = $(this).next();
                if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                    return true;
                }
                if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                    $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                    checkElement.slideDown('normal');
                }
                if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });

        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: can you show us the html code?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I understood correctly but in common case you can emulate clicking on menu when you need it (for example when page loaded):

```
$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click();
```